# PHP query insert '0' value to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]My php file inserts into table row 0 values, I cannot find solution for that.

```
<?php
$selected_button = $_POST['a'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
  $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (member_id, question_id, answer) VALUES (1, 2,'$selected_button')";

mysql_select_db('ipad',$conn);
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$result)
{
    return false;
}
return true;


mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

after insert i receive, member_id = 0 ; question_id = 0 ; answer = NULL

Comment: How does your schema look like?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated, consider replacing with the supported http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: adding your schema here will be useful to spot the issue.

Comment: change `$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);` to `$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());` and check if it breaks the code..

Comment: btw your database name is not `ipad` .. referring to the screenshot..

Comment: i know, i cutted here for some purposes

Comment: try the `die` thing and let us know if it breaks..

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mysql, it should be:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

But try to use mysqli as mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Was waiting till someone finally spots this :) Gz, you are the winner!

Comment: i have this right now, and problem is the same, earlier i tried with mysqli also, and the same problem occure

Answer (score 0):

There is no query running right now. query is first paramter in mysql_query.
`$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);`